# Have cloned GIT repo but cant see the repo in Github

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

Ive given my SSH key to the maintainer of a GIT repository. My key must have been added as I was able to clone the repository locally.

Now I want to see a list of my commits in Github but I cant see them or even the repository. Where would I find this and is it possible to have your SSH key allowed but not be added to the repo in Github?

Comment: Have you pushed your local commits to the remote repository?

Comment: Yes Ive been doing that successfully.

Comment: Is it a private github repository? - if yes the owner should give your account read/weite acces and not just your ssh key

Comment: So github access is seperate to git access? In https://github.com/my-uername?tab=repositories I dont see it. Does that mean I dont have github access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the repository is a private one. So its only accesible if you are the owner or acces is explicitely granted.

On github you can give access to user accounts (i.e., access via https possible) and also to ssh keys (e.g. for buildbots which are not associated to an account but only with a repository; this way this ssh key can only access this repo but no other repos - this can be useful to mitigate security issues if this ssh key gets compromised).

I suppose the latter case is the case you are in.